# Angular JS Controller scope and private functions and variables

Tags: scope, controller, parent

I'm having an issue, I did a Little application a few months ago in angular, but in order to extend my knowledge about angular I decide to add a funcionality and complexity to my code.
So no I inject the module and the controller and I use app config and ng-route.
Now I have something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(appConfig);
app.controller('TestController', ['$http', TestController])

function appConfig($routeProvider){
     $routeProvider.when('/', {     
         templateUrl: './test.html',
         controller: 'TestController',
         controllerAs:  'my'
    });
} 
function TestController($http ) {
    this.statusForm = 'Incompleto';
    a();
}
function a(){
    statusForm='Finalizado';
    ¿HOW DO I ACCES STATUSFORM TO CHANGE ITS VALUE IN TestController?
}
```

So that's my question, how do I change from a private function called inside the cotroller without $scope. 
Is there anyway to refer the testcontroller function's scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer to my question. I feel a bit of shame because the answer is a bit simple. I should figured it out much sooner and easier than I did.
Ok, I'm explaining it, originally i had this:

```
function TestController($http ) {
    this.statusForm = 'Incompleto';
    a();
}
function a(){
    statusForm='Finalizado';
    ¿HOW DO I ACCES STATUSFORM TO CHANGE ITS VALUE IN TestController?
}
```

And the problema was that statusform was not accesiblo at function a, before when it was using $scope it was accesible.

```
function TestController($http ) {
    this.statusForm = 'Incompleto';
    a(**this**);
}
function a(**padre**){
    **padre**.statusForm='Finalizado';
}
```

So I've changed it this way(see changes between **) and now it Works. I thought i would have some angulars way to not to send the parameter to the function "a", but i didn't find any.
Any way this way Works.
If anyone has ever the same doubt i hope this help. Greetings.